# Seria possível identificar se uma DIV está sobre outra DIV utilizando algum tipo de script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Eu tenho uma DIV A, que se movimenta em tela através do click nas teclas do teclado. Seria possível identificar se essa DIV A está sobre uma DIV B utilizando algum script e disparar um evento ao ser reconhecido a posição dessa div sobre a outra?

Código para Movimentar a DIV - A em tela

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;

    function keyPressed(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
        return String.fromCharCode(key);
    }

    document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
        var str = keyPressed(evt);

        if(str == "w" || str == "W"){

            top = top -4;
            jQuery(".person").css({ top: top + '%'});
            jQuery("#person").attr('src', 'View/img/person-back' + '.png');

        }else if(str == "s" || str == "S"){

            top = top +4;
            jQuery(".person").css({ top: top + '%'});
            jQuery("#person").attr('src', 'View/img/person-front' + '.png');

        }else if(str == "d" || str == "D"){

            left = left +4;
            jQuery(".person").css({ left: left + '%'});
            jQuery("#person").attr('src', 'View/img/person-right' + '.png');

        }else if(str == "a" || str == "A"){

            left = left -4;
            jQuery(".person").css({ left: left + '%'});
            jQuery("#person").attr('src', 'View/img/person-left' + '.png');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Podes mostrar o código que tens e que move essa div?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e inseri o código utilizado para movimentar a DIV em tela.

Comment: Podes colocar o teu HTML também? há várias `.person`?

Comment: O que é uma sobreposição válida?: quando o objeto "tocar" noutro, quando metade estiver sobreposto ou somente quando todo o objeto estiver dentro de outro?

Comment: A sobreposição poderia ser a colisão entre os objetos, apenas gostaria de identificar quando a e b colidissem entre eles para disparar uma ação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você poderia usar `getBoundingClientRect()` para conseguir uma caixa de colisão e usar um pouco de matemática para testar se as 2 `ClientRect`s estão colidindo.

Demostração: [no codepen](https://codepen.io/Cold_Meson_06/pen/JJEzEE)

Comment: Caro amigo obrigado pela solução proposta. Acredito que isso irá solucionar o meu problema.