# Como Fazer uma Regra no JavaScript de Acordo com a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Boa Noite pessoal.

Quero uma regra feita através de javascrit/Jquery que me faça o seguinte:Se o input com ID='A' estiver (DENTRO) da div com ID='B' faça algo...Ou seja quero saber quando um elemento está dentro de uma determinada div eu consiga fazer uma determinada ação.

Comment: Podia esclarecer mais um pouco a pergunta. Da forma que está é muito difícil saber o que vc quer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia usar `getBoundingClientRect()` para conseguir uma caixa de colisão e usar um pouco de matemática para testar se as 2 `ClientRects` estão colidindo.

Demostração: no [codepen](https://codepen.io/Cold_Meson_06/pen/JJEzEE). Você pode arrastar a div verde para ver. nessa regra ela fica em vermelho.

Link de referencia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213577/seria-poss%C3%ADvel-identificar-se-uma-div-est%C3%A1-sobre-outra-div-utilizando-algum-tipo)